# CoreData vs UserDefaults for saving user deletions

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm just starting out and I've used UserDefaults once or twice, never used CoreData, so I'm not sure which to use in this situation. I have a table view, which has cells populated from an empty array, which is is populated by an array of strings, depending on the page title.

In other words, I have a function in viewDidLoad which checks the navigationItem.title, and depending on what it is, populates the empty array with the correct strings. Everything loads well but I need deleted items to remain deleted. Here is my code:

Initializations:

```
    static var places = [String]()
    var nycPlaces = ["Central Park", "Rockefeller Center", "Empire State Building"]
    var londonPlaces = ["London Eye", "Windsor Castle", "Tower of London"]
    var parisPlaces = ["Champs Elysee", "Eiffel Tower", "Catacombs"]
```

This is the function that populates the table view with the correct array - this is called in viewDidLoad:

```
func populateCells() {

    switch navigationItem.title {
    case "New York":
        ListController.places = nycPlaces
    case "London":
        ListController.places = londonPlaces
    default:
        ListController.places = parisPlaces
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And to delete, I have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        ListController.places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I navigate away from the page then re-load it, the empty array is re-popoulated with the 3 strings, regardless of which ones had been deleted before. How do I ensure that the deleted cell doesn't come back?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am going to go against the answers below and say "learn and use core data".  Attempting to make user defaults operate as an object persistence system will just end up wasting time as your app or your requirements become more complex.

Comment: That's a fair comment @Paulw11. It really does depend on how complicated you intend to go with this. If somewhere down the road you want these lists populated by the response of a RESTful service or if you want to potentially have a more types of locations or sub regions, then CoreData could very well be a more viable option. Also, CoreData is a good thing to know regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use UserDefaults if your app is a simple as the code you posted (i.e. you're not fetching the data from some remote server and it really is just a few hard-coded values).

CoreData has a steep learning curve, it is difficult to use, and difficult to use correctly.  And it is overkill for the scenario you have presented.

Also note: if you don't need this to persist across your process exiting and restarting you can just create mutable arrays that live somewhere accessible by all your classes (e.g. your AppDelegate, a global singleton class, whatever) and just modify them in place.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is mostly static data, I would advise against having the overhead of CoreData. Instead I would use this approach:

```
var nycPlaces: [String] {
    get {
        guard let retval = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "nyc") as? [String] else {
            return ["Central Park", "Rockefeller Center", "Empire State Building"]
        }

        return retval
    } set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "nyc")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

var londonPlaces: [String] {
    get {
        guard let retval = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "london") as? [String] else {
            return ["London Eye", "Windsor Castle", "Tower of London"]
        }

        return retval
    } set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "london")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

var parisPlaces: [String] {
    get {
        guard let retval = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "paris") as? [String] else {
            return ["Champs Elysee", "Eiffel Tower", "Catacombs"]
        }

        return retval
    } set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "paris")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        ListController.places.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        switch navigationItem.title {
        case "New York":
            nycPlaces = ListController.places
        case "London":
            londonPlaces = ListController.places
        default:
            parisPlaces = ListController.places
        }            

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

P.S. - I'd also advise to have this data at a more global scope and to use an enum instead of doing string comparison against your navigation item's title :)

Comment: There is no need to call `synchronize`

Comment: So I gave this a shot but got a crash when I tried to delete: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Also FYI I unwrapped navigationItem.title, and switched nycPlaces = ListController.places to be the other way around, etc.

Comment: This indicates that you deleted the row from the table, but you didn't delete it from the underlying array.

Comment: ListController.places.remove(at: indexPath.row) would remove it from the array though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Your error would occur if "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int" is still returning 3. Make sure you're giving an updated count there.

Comment: @Jake I'm returning ListController.places.count